# Sitecore 10.1 slow sites after the migration from Sitecore 8.2

Tags: performance-optimization, migration, performance

We migrated to Sitecore 10.1 from Sitecore 8.2. Every site loading for the first time seems to be pretty slow.

The initial load takes 15 to 30 seconds on average and it's the `type document` which takes 15 to 30 seconds.

[image: initial load]

The load for the second refresh is fine. We never had this issue in Sitecore 8.2.

The Solr indexes are pretty huge as well. Is this cause by the large indexes?.

```
The sitecore_master_index is 630442 documents and the sitecore_web_index is 325495 documents
```

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please make sure your Xconnect website is working fine after upgrade?

Comment: Can you please check what kind of errors your are getting in your log files, or you can check your Network if any third party API that you are using on page is not working.

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat The xconnect is working

Comment: @RishirajShekhawat No errors in the log and there are no third-party API on the page

Comment: can you please try one more way by removing components one by one from page and then analyze performance of page.

Comment: @RishirajShekhawat its happening for all the sites. I have 50+ sites.

Comment: try on home page of any of the website first by removing components one by one

Comment: try to open the page in Experience Editor Debug mode to analyze which component is causing this behavior.